# How do I set java:comp/DefaultDataSource in WildFly?

Tags: java, jdbc, wildfly-8

According to the JEE spec, there should be a default data source provided to applications using `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`.  WildFly out of the box will provide that data source as per the spec.

What I can't seem to find is a way of changing the value to point somewhere else without changing the `java:comp/DefaultDataSource` mapping on the application itself.

Under "Container" -> "JPA Subsystem" there's a Default DataSource which I have tried setting, but the connection still goes to the 
`java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS`

```
@Resource(name = "somedatasource", lookup = "java:comp/DefaultDataSource")
private DataSource ds;
```

One thing to note, I am not using JPA for the application, I just wanted to get the default data source and use raw JDBC calls as I am working with a lot of LOB data and *dynamic table names* and it is more only possible on raw JDBC.

The way I test it is

```
System.out.println(ds.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL());
```

Which yields `jdbc:h2:mem:test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your standalone.xml in your favourite editor and locate the line in the `urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0` subsystem that says:

```
<default-bindings
   context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default"
   datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"
   jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"
   managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default"
   managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default"
   managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

and set the `datasource` value to the physical datasource name that you would like to be mapped to `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`.

Comment: Looks good, I'll try this later today and if it works this should be the accepted answer.  Is there no way to do this through the UI?